# MySQL - COUNT(*) cannot be converted into a string

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

Here is the full error.

```
Catchable fatal error: Object of class mysqli_result could not be converted to string in                
.../test/submit.php on line 11.
```

Here are the lines of code it is referring to.

```
$classId = $mysqli->query("SELECT COUNT(id) FROM class");
$classId += 1;

echo $classId;
```

I'm not sure if the statement isn't a returning an int, because when I'm in phpMyAdmin and do the same SQL statement, I get an int returned.

Thanks.

Comment: You have to fetch a row from the result resource `$classID`. Its value is not merely the scalar integer you queried for.

Comment: Many examples are available [in the `mysqli_result::fetch_array()` documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-result.fetch-array.php) -- Something like `$row = $classID->fetch_array(); echo $row[0];`

Comment: If you're not sure - read a manual.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't realize this was a duplicated question. heir situation wasn't really the same as mine apart from the error. I thought COUNT was supposed to return an int and I was doing that part wrong.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to fetch the object first. Something like the following should suffice:

```
$result = $mysqli->query("SELECT COUNT(id) as `count` FROM class");

$row = $result->fetch_object();

$classId = $row->count;

$classId += 1;

echo $classId;
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer! I Didn't realize this was a duplicated question? I searched for it and couldn't find anything similar to my situation with COUNT and returning an int.